# How to save changes of an HTML table full of text fields to a db

Tags: html, database, html-table, save

I have an HTML table full of text fields. I have the ability to add new rows in the table (I am just doing this with a JavaScript function call and inserting them directly) on the fly. I need to be able to save the table values right into a (MYSQL through PHP) database. I have got the database all hooked up, but I have a question about saving the changes to my table.

How can I know which fields of the potentially dozens of fields are 'dirty'? I am thinking it would be easiest to just clear out the database when I need to save and insert all of the data from the HTML table into the database. Is that an acceptable approach?

Comment: You are going to change the data-storing system from the HTML table to the DB, right? So, first of all, I think, it all depends on how do you "add new rows in the table on the fly". If you're asking about which way is better - HTML table or database, then it all depends on how many data you are going to store there. In most cases using db is easier and more correct.

Comment: There's so many missing parts here. What are you using for a database? What are you using for a server-side framework? How are you manipulating the data client side? How is the client side interacting with the server side? What do you mean by 'dirty'?

Comment: Sorry for the poorly written question. I rewrote some parts of it with more information. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's better to clear out all relevant records and re-add them. It saves a lot of messing around BUT do be sure the table you're saving contains all the relevant data. If you have state data that wouldn't normally be editable (like creationDate you should be sure it's available to resave.

You should also wrap the whole process in a transaction so you can roll back any deletions if saving the new data fails for any reason.